# How to avoid instanceOf and dynamic getter check?

Tags: java, object, oop, design-patterns

This code is from the `CardUtility` class I am using in my application.

```java
public static boolean areBothColoredAndHaveSameColor(Card c1, Card c2) {
    if (c1 instanceof ColoredCard coloredCard1 && c2 instanceof ColoredCard coloredCard2)
        return coloredCard1.getColor() == coloredCard2.getColor();
    return false;
}

public static boolean areBothNumberedAndHaveSameNumber(Card c1, Card c2) {
    if (c1 instanceof NumberedCard numberedCard1 && c2 instanceof NumberedCard numberedCard2)
        return numberedCard1.getNumber() == numberedCard2.getNumber();
    return false;
}

public static boolean areBothSpecialAndHaveSameSpeciality(Card c1, Card c2) {
    if (c1 instanceof SpecialColoredCard specialColoredCard1 && c2 instanceof SpecialColoredCard specialColoredCard2)
        return specialColoredCard1.getSpeciality() == specialColoredCard2.getSpeciality();
    return false;
}
```

I can obviously see the code duplication happening here but I am bound by the fact that I can't use an `equals` check and because of the inheritance hierarchy: `NumberedCard` and `SpecialColoredCard` both extend the abstract `ColoredCard` class. How can I avoid redundancy? Should I make all of these implement a new `CardWithKeyProperty interface` and refactor these methods to a single `doBothHaveTheSameKeyProperty()` method? But again I am not sure because `ColoredCard` is one step higher in the inheritance hierarchy so all of them implementing the same interface doesn't sound right.

Comment: Why can't you use equals? There is a typical pattern that is also generated by most IDEs which checks for strict type equality, this.getClass() == that.getClass()

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that if you run into these problems, inheritance may not be the best thing to begin with. Is a NumberedCard really a ColoredCard? To me it seems that having a number and having a color are two unrelated properties that could be present at the same time. Maybe you just need an optional Number and Color for every Card?

Comment: @Clashsoft Because for a NumberedCard to be `equal` it must have the same color too but I do not check that in my method. Same for the SpecialColoredCard

Comment: @Clashsoft Yes, a NumberedCard is a ColoredCard in the [UNO Card Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_(card_game)) that I am developing.

Comment: Ok, but you can still model it differently and just use a single Card class for everything. Inheritance is not always the right tool for the job and in this case I would't bother with it to avoid the problems you describe.

Comment: @Clashsoft if I keep numbers and speciality in the single card class, then also I will have to perform these if checks and with new boolean and null checks because NumebredCards don't have a speciality and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, but generally null checks are at least cleaner than instanceof checks.

Answer (score 3):

- Put the getters on your base card class, but make their return type `Optional<Colour>`, `Optional<Integer>` etc so that cards which don't have that characteristic can return `Optional.empty()`.

Then your code can look like this:

```java
    enum UnoColour {
        RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE
    }
    interface Card {
        Optional<Integer> getNumber();
        Optional<UnoColour> getColour();
    }

    public static boolean areBothColoredAndHaveSameColor(Card c1, Card c2) {
        return compareCards(c1, c2, c -> c.getColour());
    }

    public static boolean areBothNumberedAndHaveSameNumber(Card c1, Card c2) {
        return compareCards(c1, c2, c -> c.getNumber());
    }

    
    public static <T> boolean compareCards(Card a, Card b, Function<Card,Optional<T>> extractor) {
        Optional<T> aValue = extractor.apply(a);
        Optional<T> bValue = extractor.apply(b);
        
        return aValue.isPresent() && bValue.isPresent() && aValue.get().equals(bValue.get());
    }
```

So `compareCards` removes the duplicated code.

We can make the code more idiomatic (although perhaps harder to understand if you are not familiar with the features used), by using a method reference instead of an explicit lambda:

```java
        return compareCards(c1, c2, Card::getNumber);
```

And using `map` in `compareCards`:

```java
    public static <T> boolean compareCards(Card a, Card b, Function<Card,Optional<T>> extractor) {
        return extractor.apply(a)
           .flatMap(at -> extractor.apply(b).map(bt -> at.equals(bt)))
           .orElse(false);
    }
```

You can still use subclasses for each type of card, e.g.:

```java
class ColouredCard implements Card {

        private final Optional<UnoColour> colour;

        ColouredCard(UnoColour colour) {
            this.colour = Optional.of(colour);
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> getNumber() {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<UnoColour> getColour() {
            return colour;
        }
    }
```

It may be useful to have a static type for a `Card` to catch errors at compile time -- without seeing your code I don't know how useful that will be:

```java
  ColouredCard c = new ColouredCard(BLUE);
  functionWhichOnlyTakesNumberedCards(c); // <-- helpful compile time error
```

Answer (score 1):

like mentioned in a comment, inheritance isn't always the best solution.
Modeling this scenario with NumberedCard and ColoredCard is imho not very useful. Because a colored card will always have a number and a numbered card will always have a color, so why separate these concepts.

I would create two classes. One as NormalCard with color and number and the other as SpecialCard. And in an interface Card should exists a method compatibleTo().

just my 2c

Comment: So, every card has a color? Sorry it's a long time ago that i played UNO

Comment: No WildCards, Draw 4s (not yet added to the game) do not have color.

Comment: Ok got it, What would happen if you model specialty and number  as a value of a card?

Comment: So why not use this enum for numbers too, because as far as i remember the only operation applied to this numbers is comparision

Answer (score 1):

Like tgdavies’s solution, I would use a Function argument, but I wouldn’t modify the Card subclasses.  (I’m not saying I agree with your inheritance hierarchy, but I don’t have enough information to really question it.)

```
private static <C extends Card> boolean attributeMatches(
                                            Card c1,
                                            Card c2,
                                            Class<C> cardType,
                                            Function<C, ?> attribute) {

    return cardType.isInstance(c1) && cardType.isInstance(c2)
        && Objects.equals(attribute.apply(c1), attribute.apply(c2));
}

public static boolean sameColor(Card c1, Card c2) {
    return attributeMatches(c1, c2, ColoredCard, ColoredCard::getColor);
}

public static boolean sameNumber(Card c1, Card c2) {
    return attributeMatches(c1, c2, NumberedCard, NumberedCard::getNumber);
}

public static boolean sameSpecialty(Card c1, Card c2) {
    return attributeMatches(c1, c2, SpecialColoredCard, SpecialColoredCard::getSpecialty);
}
```